# REST request fails with URI encoded path parameter

Tags: angularjs, resteasy, urlencode

I use **AngularJS** (client) and a **REST interface** in my project (server, `javax.ws.rs.*`). I'm passing data in a path parameter. It may contain *special characters*, so I call `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the arguments prior to sending a request.

**Client-side:**

```
$http.put('/foo/data/' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '/bar');
```

The controller will process the request and send a response.

**Server-side:**

```
@PUT
@Path("/data/{data}/bar")
public ResultObject handleFooRequest(@PathParam("data") String data) throws Exception {
  return handleRequest(data);
}
```

This works fine on `localhost`, however, the request fails when I do a request on our production server (*Error 400: Bad request*). What am I doing wrong and why is it working on one server and fails on the other? In general, is my approach correct? Do I need to tell RESTEasy to decode the arguments? To my understanding (I read the documentation), it does that on default.

Comment: Any reason not putting data in body? E.g. u know that url length is limited?

Comment: Yes, I know. The argument contains a date for filtering and is supposed to be passed by URI.

Comment: Anyway first thing to check is quite obvious - run request manually (e.g. using Postman) to understand if this is UI or BE issue.